# How to divide Spark DataFrame one row by its next row value using Scala functions

Tags: list, scala, dataframe, division

I have a Spark Data frame like this and want divide its first row by next row using Scala only and not by Spark Functions. Where getting some issues and looking for suggestions.

```
+------+
|number|
+------+
|24    |
|12    |
+------+
```

Here output should be 2 as dividing 24/12 = 2

Below is the code what I am trying :

```
    val spark = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .appName("Spark Test")
      .getOrCreate()
    
    val testDF1 = spark.sql("""select string("24") as number""")
    val testDF2 = spark.sql("""select string("12") as number""")
    val testDF = testDF1.union(testDF2)
    testDF.show(false)

    import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
    def divideRows = udf((columnValue: String) => {
      var result = ""
      val dfAslist = testDF.collectAsList()
      result = dfAslist.get(0)/dfAslist.get(1)
      result
    })

   //Applying UDF Method on DataFrame Column
    val finalDividedDF =  testDF.withColumn("dividedValue", divideRows(testDF("columnValue")))
```

Output value of this should be 2. Please help.

Comment: If you want to do that using Scala functions you will need a UDAF. I can provide an example, although for this task I would suggest to use Spark Windows.

Comment: Hi @EmiCareOfCell44, if possible please provide example, I can't use Spark window due to restrictions of multiple aggregation in Spark Streaming. That's why looking for Scala Solution.

Answer (score 0):

Although this task can be solved with a simple Window operation if you need to do this custom aggregation without using SparkSql functions you must use an Spark UDAFs. The problem here is that  "in a grouped aggregation, aggregate values (e.g. counts) are maintained for each unique value in the user-specified grouping column. In case of window-based aggregations, aggregate values are maintained for each window the event-time of a row falls into". you can use your custom aggregation extract the result in an Array and then explode that column.

Your UDAF code could be something like:

```
class GenericOperation
  (func: (Double, Double) => Double)
  extends UserDefinedAggregateFunction {

  private def combinations2[A](input: List[A]): List[(A, A)] =
    input match {
      case h :: t if !t.isEmpty => (h, t.head) :: combinations2(t)
      case h => Nil
      case Nil => Nil
    }

  /** Internal buffer to apply transformations **/
  private val bufferType = ArrayType(DoubleType)

  override def inputSchema: StructType =
    StructType(List(StructField("value", DoubleType)))

  override def bufferSchema: StructType =
    StructType(StructField("internal_buffer", bufferType) :: Nil)

  override def dataType: DataType = ArrayType(DoubleType)

  override def deterministic: Boolean = true

  override def initialize(buffer: MutableAggregationBuffer): Unit = {
    buffer(0) = Array[Double]()
  }

  override def update(buffer: MutableAggregationBuffer, input: Row): Unit = {
    buffer(0) = buffer.getAs[mutable.WrappedArray[Double]](0).+:(input.getAs[Double](0))
  }

  override def merge(buffer1: MutableAggregationBuffer, buffer2: Row): Unit = {
    buffer1(0) = buffer1.getAs[mutable.WrappedArray[Double]](0) ++ (buffer2.getAs[mutable.WrappedArray[Double]](0))
  }

  override def evaluate(buffer: Row): Any = {
    val sequence = buffer.getAs[mutable.WrappedArray[Double]](0)
    val c = combinations2(sequence.toList).toList
    val combination = c.map(el => func(el._1, el._2)).toArray
    combination
  }
}
```

One example application:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{lit, max}

implicit val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").getOrCreate()

val data = Seq(Row(1, 24.0), Row(2, 12.0), Row(3, 48.0), Row(4, 56.0))

val df = spark
    .createDataFrame(spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data),
      StructType(List(StructField("order", IntegerType), StructField("value", DoubleType))))

  def main(args: Array[String]) : Unit = {

    import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
    import spark.implicits._

    val aggregation = new GenericOperation((a, b) => a / b)

    df.agg(aggregation('value))
      .flatMap(el => el.getAs[mutable.WrappedArray[Double]](0)).show()

}
```

the output is:

```
+------------------+
|             value|
+------------------+
|               2.0|
|              0.25|
|0.8571428571428571|
+------------------+
```

I didn´t check with a structured streaming source. I think it will work but, besides this a little weird implementation(it should be done with a window, if possible), problems arise what happen between mini batches?. You can better try this option and tell me the problems that you find.